# CLOCKS_PER_SEC Not Matching Results From std::clock()

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, time, clock

I'm using the following short program to test `std::clock()`:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    std::clock_t Begin = std::clock();

    int Dummy;
    std::cin >> Dummy;

    std::clock_t End = std::clock();

    std::cout << "CLOCKS_PER_SEC: " << CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
    std::cout << "Begin: " << Begin << "\n";
    std::cout << "End: " << End << "\n";
    std::cout << "Difference: " << (End - Begin) << std::endl;
}
```

However, after waiting several seconds to input the "dummy" value, I get the following output:

```
CLOCKS_PER_SEC: 1000000
Begin: 13504
End: 13604
Difference: 100
```

This obviously doesn't make much sense.  No matter how long I wait, the difference is always somewhere around 100.

What am I missing?  Is there some header I forgot to include?

I'm using Xcode with GCC 4.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`clock()` counts CPU time, so it's not adding any time if it's sitting around waiting for input.

Comment: Arg.  Are there any standard alternatives?  I can't use `time()` because I need finer resolution than seconds.

Comment: @Maxpm: Hmmm, [clock_gettime()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) might work.

Comment: `boost::timer` uses `clock()` as well, it seems.  `clock_gettime()` looks good, but I don't want to deal with porting it to Windows.  Oh, well.

Comment: @Maxpm: Yes, so I discovered. That's why I edited Boost.Timer out of my comment. The `progress_timer` looked more interesting, but it simply outputs the elapsed time in its destructor. I'm surprised Boost doesn't have what you are looking for.

Comment: Use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` on POSIX and `GetTickCount`/`QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows.  `clock` really isn't useful for anything portable, because it counts CPU time in C and wall time in VC++.

Comment: This is something you *do* have to implement one way for UNIX and one way for Windows.